# How to get the value in a nested `ArrayListMultimap`

Tags: java, arraylist, guava, multimap

I have the following code for a nested `ArrayListMultimap`:

```
    Multimap<String, Multimap<Integer, String>> doubleMultiMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    Multimap<Integer, String> doc = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    doc.put(1, "ABC");
    doc.put(2, "BCD");
    doc.put(1, "XYZ");
    doubleMultiMap.put("D123", doc);

    doc = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    doc.put(1, "John");
    doc.put(2, "Jane");
    doc.put(2, "George");
    doubleMultiMap.put("J123", doc);
    System.out.println(doubleMultiMap.get("D123"));
```

For `doubleMultiMap.get("D123")` I get the result as `[{1=[ABC, XYZ], 2=[BCD]}]`

But how to get the value for keys `D123, 1`. I tried to use `(doubleMultiMap.get("D123")).get(1)` but it is not supported.

**Update:**
What I'm trying to achieve is something like below. If nested `Multimap` is not ideal, what alternative could I use?

[image]

Comment: Do you really need a double multi map? Your example and your tried code looks like you actually want `Map<String, Multimap<Integer, String>>`.

Comment: May I add that using a nested Multimap is a very bad idea? A Multimap is about the complexest data structure you should use.

Comment: @Tom that's equivalent to the `Multitable` interface that's [been discussed for years](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/902)

Comment: I added a description of my objective, if multimap is not ideal, what else could I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need [`Table`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Table.html)-specific methods like row or column access (and it seems you don't, since you want to access `D123, 1`), compound key for `Multimap` is the solution. Create simple class storing string and integer with proper `hashCode` and `equals` and use multimap normally. Assuming your compound key class name is `Key` (you should think of better one) you should be able to do something like this:

```
//given
ListMultimap<Key, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create(); // note ListMultimap
multimap.put(new Key("D123", 1), "ABC");
multimap.put(new Key("D123", 2), "BCD");
multimap.put(new Key("D123", 1), "XYZ");
multimap.put(new Key("J123", 1), "John");
multimap.put(new Key("J123", 2), "Jane");
multimap.put(new Key("J123", 2), "George");
//when
List<String> values = multimap.get(new Key("D123", 1));
//then
assertThat(values).containsExactly("ABC", "XYZ");
```

If you need to access [by row](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Table.html#row-R-) or [by column](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Table.html#column-C-) (ex. get complete mapping of column `2` which in your case would have keys `"D123"` and `"J123"`), then you may want to settle with `Table<String, Integer, List<String>>` and take care of creating lists in table values on demand (sadly, there's no `computeIfAbsent` in `Table` interface).

Third option would be to discuss `Multitable` in [this Guava issue](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/902), as mentioned by @SeanPatrickFloyd in the comment above.

Comment: When you said to use proper `hashcode` and `equals`, is it like this: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/hashcode-equals.html

Comment: I meant following the contract between [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) and [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29). Most IDEs can generate those methods for you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what `get` returns is a `Collection` (of `Multimap` in your case). [Take a look](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#get-K-):

> Collection get(@Nullable
>                     K key)
>
> Returns a view collection of the values associated with key in this
>   multimap, if any. Note that when containsKey(key) is false, this
>   returns an empty collection, not null.
>
> Changes to the returned collection will update the underlying
>   multimap, and vice versa.

To get the nested Multimap do this:

```
Iterator<Multimap<Integer, String>> iter = doubleMultiMap.get("D123").iterator();
Multimap<Integer, String> nested = iter.next();
```

Comment: You can get a list through the `ListMultimap` interface. But the correct index would be 0.